# What do you use to make your course materials?

Tags: secondary-education

I'm a second year teacher teaching Precal for the first time.

I have a few textbooks, but the problem is that my school does not (and will never) have class sets of any of them for students to use.

To make worksheets using the textbook would therefore be copyright infringement.

I've looked at some of the EngageNY/Eureka Math stuff but it's hard to edit/move around.

Kuta is good but it's mostly for drilling with little/no conceptual. Same with IXL and DeltaMath which I have access to.

I've dropped hundreds on TPT materials but they're not very good. They're not tailored to the particular kids I'm teaching.

Math teachers, how do you make your materials?

Comment: Is this high school? Perhaps mentioning the country you're in would help us to answer you, also. There are free precalculus textbooks. Openstax provides one. (https://openstax.org/details/books/precalculus) There may well be better ones out there. (OER means open educational resources. You can search on that plus precalculus to find others.)

Comment: Also, you may contact me personally for particular materials, if you'd like.

Comment: This question is vastly too broad. Materials for what level? What topic? What exact audience? ("precalc" is a meaningless grouping, are these a strong cohort or a weak one, how precisely were they taught fundamental techniques and concepts?) Digital, tactile, or other types? How directed is the learning - monkey see monkey do or investigation projects, or a template project?

Comment: And alongside that, how much mathematics do **you** know? To what depth and expertise? How capable are you of matching appropriate contexts and topics? How well do you understand what they need to learn, versus preferable versus optional versus pointless make-work?

Comment: I am confused... how is making worksheets using the textbook likely to constitute copyright infringement?  Unless you are simply photocopying the text, there should be no problem.  I also agree with Nij---your problem is poorly specified.

Comment: Both Finland and Norway have specific agreements on making copies of different materials for school use. I do not know the situation in other countries, but imagine they have something like this, too. You may wish to specify your country so that knowledgeable people can comment on these kinds of issues.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I guess we should assume the OP is thinking of something where copyright would be an issue. [It could be typing out, word-for-word, an activity from a book.]